# TSQL Select from many tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database like this!

**Students**:

```
StudentID     PK
FirstName
LastName
...
```

**Courses**:

```
CourseID    PK
SubjectID   FK
CourseName
...
```

**StudentsCourses**: (for many-to-many)

```
StudentCourseID   PK
StudentID     FK
CourseID      FK
```

**Subjects**:

```
SubjectID   PK
SubjectName 
...
```

**StudentScores**:

```
StudentScoreID   PK
StudentID    FK
ExamDate
...
```

Now I want to query like this:

```
StudentID | FirstName | LastName | SubjectName | CourseName | ExamDate
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This is a simple join. Try at least some basic tutorials before asking. It seems you haven't made any effort at all..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a query similar to the below.

What you want to do is use joins to connect two tables in your database to get the desired outcome. Google TSQL Join() for more information

Try this query:

```
select a.StudentID, a.Firstname, a.Lastname, d.SubjectName, c.CourseName, e.ExamDate 
from Students a
join StudentsCourses b on a.studentid = b.studentid
join Courses c on b.courseid = c.courseid
join Subjects d on c.subjectID = d.subjectID
join StudentScores e on a.studentid = e.studentid
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this query, but it don't return any data.

Comment: the reason for that would be that not all tables contain an entry for this query. You can try adding LEFT in front of all the JOIN commands